# JavaFX Material Button animation

Tags: java, javafx, material-design

I'm trying to create a material design for JavaFX, but I have a problem with the click animation. In Android there's an expanding circle inside the Button, but how can I place a Circle inside a Button in JavaFX, or is this not possible?

Comment: `button.setGraphic(circle);`?

Comment: To get some ideas you can have a look at the source code of http://jfoenix.com/, a MaterialDesign Library for JavaFx.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button">
  <graphic>
    <Circle fill="DODGERBLUE" radius="100.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
  </graphic>
</Button>
```